# Mercurial: Revert a single hunk

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, revert

How do I revert a single hunk in Mercurial, similar to the way it's done in darcs, i.e. it asks me for each hunk and file whether I want to revert it?  Is it possible using TortoiseHg?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should specify what a hunk is. I haven't much experience with Hg but I haven't seen this name in the doc when I have read it, and search 'hunk' in the Wiki gives 0 results...

Comment: By "hunk" I mean a "snippet of change", i.e. a part of the "diff".  TortoiseHg uses this terminology and so does darcs.

Comment: You can set up an external diff tool (for example: TortoiseGitMerge) in TortoiseHg options, and launch it by selecting "Diff to Parent" in the right-click menu that appears over your file in TortoiseHg. From the diff tool, it is easy to detect and revert the hunks separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`record` extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RecordExtension) is inspired by `darcs record`. It will allow you to *add* only specific hunks to the next commit, i.e., the opposite of what you want. But you could add all hunks except the one you want to revert and then do a `hg revert` to revert it. A little backwards, I know... :-)

You could also do `hg diff > patch; hg revert`, edit `patch` to delete the hunk and do `hg import --no-commit` to reappy the patch. That is likely faster, but requires you to manually edit the patch. I've had great success with the Emacs `diff-mode`, but since you ask about TortoiseHg you might not want to use Emacs.

Comment: I do use Emacs all the time, I'm just not completely familiar with the Hg support in it.   I'll look into it and hopefully it's just like any other VC mode...  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Great. I've only used Mercurial a little from within Emacs: `C-x v =` does a `hg diff` on the current file, and `C-x v v` does a `hg commit` on the current file. That is sometimes nice when I work on a repository where I know that checking in just the one file is okay.

As for editing the patch, then that is independent of Mercurial. It just uses Emacs' diff-mode which knows how to update the line numbers when you delete stuff from a patch.

Answer (score 8):

Actually mercurial refers to "chunks", at least in the Shelve tool. Which brings me to favorite way to revert them (and favorite features of TortoiseHg).

Just move the chunks you want to revert onto a shelf you create solely with the intention to delete. This works really well as long as the chunks are identified as you need them to be. If not, you've got no choice but to do something manually.

If you use TortoiseHg Workbench or VisualHg, it is very easy to get to the Shelve tool: there is a button next to the diff mode toggle buttons. If you are not familiar with shelves, do yourself a favor and start using it. It has saved me much aggravation when I've forgotton to commit early, or decided to leave out experimental code from a commit.

Comment: Now, there is a button named "Delete selected chunks" present! I would hardly discover it there myself, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

For reversing a changeset on a single file try:

> hg diff -c   | patch -R

That will reverse the changeset introduced by that revision on that filename. Now if the same darcs/git style cherry-picking behavior could be included in that somehow I would be very happy.

Comment: You probably need to make that `patch -R -p1` or higher levels of `-p`, depending on your current working directory within the repository.